# How to group by session_id in AR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.

In this app I have a Form object with one or more FormAnswer objects.
Many FormAnswer objects can share the same session_id attribute.

What I want to do is to group the FormAnswer objects by this session_id when doing the query to the database.

*Basically the output I need is this:*

```
{
"status": 200,
"total": 2,
"data": [{
    "1359105907771583": [{
        "session_id": 1359105907771583,
        "content": "example@example.com",
        "privacy": "public"
    }, {
        "session_id": 1359105907771583,
        "content": "example2@example.com",
        "privacy": "public"
    }]
}, {
    "1803075480887669": [{
        "session_id": 1803075480887669,
        "content": "example@example.com",
        "privacy": "public"
    }, {
        "session_id": 1803075480887669,
        "content": "example2@example.com",
        "privacy": "public"
    }]
}]
```

}

I know I can do something like this put then I get a hash and not an active record object so I cannot paginate:

```
FormAnswer.all.group_by(&:session_id)
```

Currently I do the grouping on the frontend now (Angular) but I need it to be done on the backend instead so I can paginate and so on.

Comment: You may need two queries. One to get the requested page of session_ids, and the second to get all FormAnswers for that page of session_ids. You can then transform the results from that second query into the needed JSON.

Comment: You need apply pagination before group_by.